# Why am I spawning random familiars as Lilith?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth

[image]So I'm playing as Lilith and for some reason I keep spawning random familiars. I picked up Little Steven but Succubus and the Leech are not familiars I acquired via shop or item room. Where did they come from?

Comment: spugsley pls. You come back and don't even visit us in chat? That's probably why you have leeches :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lilith starts with [Cambion Conception](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Cambion_Conception), an item that causes you to spawn familiars after taking a certain number of hits. The familiars awarded are random, so you'll see different familiars across different runs.

Comment: There are only a few possible familiars though, you can't get all possible familiars. It will also not remove the Gaines familiars from the item pools, so you can find them a second time in an item/devil room.

Comment: They're random, but you'll always get only demonic familiars.

Comment: As a side note, you have to unlock Cambion Conception before Lillith will start with it.

Comment: Oh my gosh. I play this game every single damn day. How did I not know this. Thanks!